# Why Stats.min.js can only be imported by `script src=` but not `import`?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jekyll

I have Javascript codes as below. When the importation is inside `<script src="..."></script>`, it works. However, if I moved the importation to `import ...;`, it doesn't work. The error message is: "Uncaught ReferenceError: Stats is not defined".

Why is that? Since I am working on a Jekyll site, I prefer to do the `import ...;` way to make sure other elements of the site work. Any idea how to do the `import ...;` way without error?

**It works**

```
  <div id="stats"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js"></script>

  <script type="module">

  const stats = new Stats()
  stats.setMode(0)
  document.getElementById('stats').appendChild(stats.domElement)
  </script>
```

**It doesn't work**

```
  <div id="stats"></div>

  <script type="module">
  import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r16/Stats.min.js';

  const stats = new Stats()
  stats.setMode(0)
  document.getElementById('stats').appendChild(stats.domElement)
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`import` allows you to import JavaScript modules which conform to the [ES6 module format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

`Stats.min.js` does not. The code is obfuscated but appears to create a global and support the old [CommonJS module format](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/).